# Writing $ inside the shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, gnuplot

I have a problem while I use $ in my script

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -e ' H2O ' molfra.out > H2O
grep -e ' C6F13 ' molfra_ig.out > C6F13
grep -e ' C8F17 ' molfra_ig.out > C8F17
grep -e ' C10F21 ' molfra_ig.out > C10F21
grep -e ' C16F33 ' molfra_ig.out > C16F33

cat > SNW_CFscheck.gnplt << EOF
reset
set terminal png enhanced
set output '800K_Chains.png'
set title "250 water and PFPE chained SNW 800K NVT MD"
set yrange [0:4]
set ytics 1
set grid
set xlabel "Time(ps)"
set ylabel "Number of molecules"
plot "C6F13" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_6F_{13}", \
  "C8F17" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_8F_{17}", \
  "C10F21" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_{10}F_{21}", \
  "C16F33" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_{16}F_{33}"
EOF

gnuplot SNW_CFscheck.gnplt
```

So, I create a file named 'SNW_CFscheck.gnplt' using cat command, and execute the file 
But $1 is not recognized inside the cat command, (or $1 is recognized as global variable?) so the code doesn't work.

How can I use $ inside this scripts?

Thanks

Comment: Expansions **do** occur inside of heredocs (the syntax is not in any way `cat`-specific) unless you quote the sigil: `<<'EOF'` would prevent them.

Comment: ...and, to be clear, `$1` expands to the first command-line argument given to your script.

Comment: To avoid any problems with gnuplot scripts, independent of the environment, use `column(1)` instead of the shortcut `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using an escape character? Like "\$"?

Answer (score 4):

If you want `$1` not to be expanded then quote the EOF like this:

```
cat > SNW_CFscheck.gnplt << 'EOF'
reset
set terminal png enhanced
set output '800K_Chains.png'
set title "250 water and PFPE chained SNW 800K NVT MD"
set yrange [0:4]
set ytics 1
set grid
set xlabel "Time(ps)"
set ylabel "Number of molecules"
plot "C6F13" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_6F_{13}", \
  "C8F17" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_8F_{17}", \
  "C10F21" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_{10}F_{21}", \
  "C16F33" u ($1/10000):2 w l title "800K C_{16}F_{33}"
EOF
```

As per `man bash`:

> If any
>          characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document
>          are not expanded.

Comment: Note that *any* quoting is sufficient: `<< "EOF"` and `<< \EOF` have the same effect, as does even something bizarre like `<< E\OF`.

Comment: May I know what's wrong with this answer that you had to un-accept it after so long.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the character within double quotes "\$". Read more about the effect of Single vs Double quotes here ---> http://linux.101hacks.com/bash-scripting/quotes-inside-shell-script/

Comment: Heredocs, such as that used here, are a special case for which this advice isn't on-point.